# If $k \otimes_F A_0$ is finitely generated as an algebra over $k$, is $A_0$ finitely generated as an algebra over $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A_0$ be a unital algebra over a field $F$, and let $k$ be an algebraically closed field containing $A_0$.  Then $A = k \otimes_F A_0$ is an algebra over $k$.  If $A$ is  finitely generated as a $k$-algebra, is $A_0$ finitely generated as an $F$-algebra?

My attempt at a proof:

We can identify $A_0$ with its image in $A$.  If $A$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra, then we can clearly choose a finite generating set $f_1, ... , f_m$ which lies in $A_0$.  If $C$ is the $F$-algebra $F[f_1, ... , f_m]$, then an inclusion map of $F$-vector spaces $C \rightarrow A_0$ induces a $k$-linear transformation $k \otimes_F C \rightarrow k \otimes_F A_0$.  But this is an isomorphism, hence $C = A_0$ by faithful flatness.

Is this correct?

Comment: Two questions: 1. Did you really mean $k$ containing $A_0$ instead of $k$ containing $F$? 2. Why can we choose the $f_i$ in $A_0$?

Comment: Ah, I see: we start with some generating set, the generators are sums of homogenous elements $a_i\otimes f_i$, and so the $f_i$ are good enough to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is puzzling. Of course $C=A_0$, that's practically by definition. You can prove that the same generating set will generate $k\otimes_F A_0$ though because there is a basis of $A_0$ that is an algebraic combination of the $f_i$ over $F$. This basis will remain a basis when you take the tensor product.